# Cómo crear y ejecutar un archivo C en Bash?

Tags: c, linux, bash, vscode

Estoy empezando a conocer bash y un ejercicio me pide compilar un archivo c en bash este es mi código
lei en mi guia de ejercicios que para hacer comillas en bash tenias que anteponer un \ pero nose si lo estoy haciendo bien, sin embargo cuando intento compilar me sale un error ¿en que estoy fallando?
el error que me sale es:

```
creador.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `('
creador.sh: line 4: `int main (){'


#!/bin /bash
echo \"
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    printf("Hola amigos del curso de arqui");

    return 0;
}
\" >> hola.c
```

Gracias a todos

Comment: ¿Qué error te sale?

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya lo edite :)

Comment: Pues tal parece que no sólo debes escapar las comillas dobles, también los paréntesis (`\(`). De todas formas sería recomendable que acudieras a la [documentación oficial](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html). Saludos

Comment: En la pregunta dices que quieres compilar un archivo `.c` desde la consola, pero no también crearlo. ¿Estás seguro que es necesario crear el archivo `.c` desde bash en lugar de usar uno ya existente?

Comment: @Mateo hola, se que se puede hacer, eso pero es un ejercicio que nos dice que tenemos que crearlo en bash y ejecutarlo :)

Comment: @StefhanieJaramillo trata de evitar colocar imágenes en los posts. El error es un mensaje que se puede copiar/pegar como hiciste para colocar el contenido de tu script.

Comment: Comentario off-topic: sin mayúsculas  sostenidas, por favor.

Comment: Si la pregunta indica que se debe compilar, el contenido del post debería reflejarlo, igual que las respuestas. Hagamos un sitio con contenido bien ordenado para que sea útil para otros. Gracias =).

Answer (score 4):

1. El shebang es "`#! /bin/bash` "(el espacio está después del signo de exclamación, no después del nombre del directorio);
2. Coloque el texto que se mostrará con el comando `echo` entre comillas (" ... "), sin barras invertidas;
3. Coloque barras invertidas (\) solo en el texto del comando `echo` antes de cada comilla (");

```sh
#! /bin/bash
echo "
#include <stdio.h>
int main (){
    printf(\"Hola amigos del curso de arqui\");

    return 0;
}
" >> hola.c
```

ACTUALIZAR

Si escribe mucho código C desde un script, puede usar esta sintaxis:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
cat >> hola.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main () {
     printf ("Hola amigos del curso de arqui");

     return 0;
}
EOF
```

En este caso, utilice una barra invertida delante de cada carácter de dólar ($) y no delante de las comillas ("). El dólar se utiliza menos en C que las comillas.

Por otro lado, ¡puede usar el dólar sin barra invertida para inyectar el contenido de una variable de shell en su código C!

*Perdón por mi español. Solo soy francés :-(*

Comment: Nada que perdonar.... escribes mejor que lo que hablan varios nativos que conozco :-D

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar espacios en el shebang (salvo para incluir argumentos para el intérprete). Saludos.

Comment: @D4RIO: Mantuve este hábito desde que trabajaba en sistemas antiguos (Ultrix, OSF ...)

Answer (score 2):

Por la descripción de lo que pones, el reto es *compilar* desde bash, sin usar un IDE... en todo caso, construir archivos de esta forma es más sencillo hacerlo con `<<` que te permite escribir contenido **tal cual** en un archivo:

```
$ ls -1
construir.sh
$ cat construir.sh 
cat > hello.c <<EOF
blah "blah"
oh, yeah
EOF

$ ./construir.sh 
$ ls -1
construir.sh
hello.c
$ cat hello.c 
blah "blah"
oh, yeah
```

Algo incluso mas fancy podría ser:

```
$ gcc -o hello -x c - <<EOF
el codigo fuente
EOF
```

Eso debería crear el ejecutable directo. Si lo quieres poner en un script, bien podrías.